# Generate field of an interface by JavaPoet

Tags: java, code-generation, javapoet

Is there any way to generate a field like this:

```
public static final TypedKey<String> UM_USR = new TypedKey<String>() {};
```

I didn't find any way to set the type of UM_USR to a generic interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `ParameterizedTypeName` instead of a simple `ClassName` :

```
ParameterizedTypeName paramTypedKey = ParameterizedTypeName.get(ClassName.get(TypedKey.class), ClassName.get(String.class));
```